# MPLABX Project stopped compiling when I changed of computer

Tags: compiler-errors, pic, mplab, xc8

I'm writing firmware for a PIC18F4550 using the MPLABX and the XC8 compiler. The project was compiling with some warnings, but I was able to compile and use the hexa file to simulate. So I decided to advance the work at home. I zipped the folder where the MPLABX project was and sent it by email. When I got home, I downloaded it. I installed the MPLABX and the XC8 compiler. The version is the same one I originally used, the most recent until now, 2.05.I opened the project without making any changes, I compiled it, however, it did not compile. Errors were found, the first listing was:

*error: unknown type name 'far'*

This error did not occur before. What could have happened? Does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I think in XC8 the `far` qualifier is controlled by the `--ADDRQUAL` option. It may have been added into properties on the first installation. If you don't need to place that variable in extended memory you can omit it.

Answer (score 1):

You will encounter a lot more problems if you start using interrupts etc. Take a look at this summary for all the changes made in the latest version.

https://www.microforum.cc/topic/5-i-used-to-use-to-locate-variables-but-since-xc8-20-this-is-no-longer-working

Answer (score 0):

I already have the answer. It was given by another person to me in the Microchip forum. This is the link :

https://www.microchip.com/forums/m/tm.aspx?m=1099735

> I have noticed that when I unzip a previously packaged project and
>   open it (even on the same computer, but in a different directory)
>   MPLABX tends not to pay attention to the compiler version and settings
>   as they appear in the project's nbproject/configurations.xml file, but
>   uses defaults instead.   The default for XC8 version 2.05 is C99 mode,
>   and I suspect that if you go to the Project->Properties->->Global
>   Options window you will see the C Standard is set to C99
>
> My suggestion: Set it to C90 and see what happens.
>
> Regads,
>
> Dave